# Searching and getting specific users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have relationship between users and i want to search and get collection from connected users. Example:

Users:

```
ID: 1 | Nikola - he is TRAINER
ID: 2 | Test - he is his client
```

ClientTrainer Table:

```
trainer_id | client_id | status
1          | 2         | 1
```

When trainer search for specific users, i want to search only users who has status 1 and have relationship between them.

This is my current code:

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])){
    $names = explode(" ", $_GET['type']);
    $klijenti = User::where(function($query) use ($names) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $names);
    $query->orWhere(function($query) use ($names) {
        $query->whereIn('surname', $names);
    });
  })->orderBy("last_seen","DESC")->get();
  print_r($klijenti);
  if(empty($_GET['type'])){
    $klijenti = $user->allclients;
  }
}
```

Comment: if you setup a relationship you could use `whereHas` to filter this query based on existence of the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand your requirement, but here is one solution that utilizes relationships:

Add this to your `User` Model. This assumes that your "ClientTrainer" Table is called client_trainers.

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'client_trainers', 'trainer_id', 'client_id')
        ->wherePivot('status', 1);
}
```

**Option 1**

Now you should be able to perform queries like this, assuming that `Auth::user()` returns the currently logged in trainer:

```
$clients = Auth::user()->clients()->whereIn('name', $names)
    ->orWhereIn('surname', $names)
    ->orderBy("last_seen","DESC")->get();
```

Or to get all the clients of a single trainer just do something like

```
$clients = Auth::user()->clients()->get();
```

**Option 2**

If you want to search independently of a single trainer, you can do something like this:

```
$clients = User::has('clients')
    ->whereIn('name', $names)
    ->orWhereIn('surname', $names)
    ->orderBy("last_seen","DESC")->get();
```

The first part `User::has('clients')` should only return Users that have at least on client with `status = 1` in the client_trainers table.

Comment: You fully understand my requirement! Thanks you!!